# How to used a NamedJDBCTemplate placeholder in the where clause of a postgres ARRAY comparison?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm attempting to do a postgres query with an `ARRAY`/GIN where clause using spring-jdbc.
`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` throws an error when I attempt to use a named parameter inside an `ARRAY[]`.

minimal example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testing(col1 text[]);
INSERT INTO testing VALUES ('{item1, item2, item3}');
INSERT INTO testing VALUES ('{item4, item5, item6}');

=> select * from testing where col1 @> ARRAY['item4'];
        col1         
---------------------
 {item4,item5,item6}
```

Java:

```java
        var sql = "select * from testing where col1 @> ARRAY[:item]";
        var paramMap = Map.of("item", "item4");
        var results = namedJDBCTemplate.queryForList(sql, paramMap);
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'item]': No value registered for key 'item]'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList
```

Answer (score 0):

adding spaces around the parameter and casting it in the sql query, e.g.

```
select * from testing where col1 @> ARRAY[ CAST ( :item AS text) ]
```

fixed it